# What does this mean in derivatives?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have seen this when I am integrating things, but I haven't seen this in this context. What does it mean?

[image]

To be specific, what does $\alpha_0$ do in this calculation.

Comment: It means "put $\alpha_0$ in place of the variable".

Comment: cool thanks for the quick help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means: "When evaluated at the point $a_0$"